# How does one execute the windows runas command from inside cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, runas

If I try to use the Windows runas command from inside Cygwin the Enter password line prints to standard out but it doesn't wait for me to type my password into System.in

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can't you run the cygwin shell as admin instead?

Comment: I don't need to execute the Windows shell as admin, I need to execute as a specific account with different privileges to my own.

Comment: Then, can't you runas the cygwin shell as that specific account?

Comment: Does `cygstart --action=runas` work?

Comment: How should i pass the specific user with `cygstart --action=runas`?
Is there really no solution for this?
I need to start a script inside a existing cygwin shell that is executed as a different (specific) user.

Comment: "Runas [...] likely [...] doesn't understand Cygwin's ptys": http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Runas-command-in-cygwin-td102990.html

Comment: I tried `runas /user:$(hostname)\\$(whoami) notepad.exe` today and it waited for me to type my password. This might have been a bug that has since been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured I could use 2 nested Command Prompt window pop-ups to run a password-changing script,

```
cygstart cmd /c "runas /user:DOMAIN\\USER \"powershell %cd%\\changepw.ps1\" & pause"
```

The changepw.ps1 script follows,

```
# http://serverfault.com/questions/570476/how-can-a-standard-windows-user-change-their-password-from-the-command-line
# cygstart cmd /c "runas /user:DOMAIN\\USER \"powershell %cd%\\changepw.ps1\" & pause"

param (
    [string]$oldPassword = $( Read-Host "Old password"),
    [string]$newPassword = $( Read-Host "New password")
)

$ADSystemInfo = New-Object -ComObject ADSystemInfo
$type = $ADSystemInfo.GetType()
$user = [ADSI] "LDAP://$($type.InvokeMember('UserName', 'GetProperty', $null, $ADSystemInfo, $null))"
try {
    $user.ChangePassword($oldPassword, $newPassword)
} catch [Exception] {
    # echo $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message
    echo $_.Exception | format-list -force
}
write-host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting a "Cygwin Terminal", you can start a "[Cygwin Console](https://superuser.com/a/365155/759582)". You can do this by executing

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --Login
```

Then, you should be able to run native Windows commands like `runas`.

(However, you lose some POSIX compatibility, because the shell will run in a Windows console window and not inside a MinTTY terminal.)